# Expected no output and different output

Tags: python

I'm doing this exercise:

> **Write multiple if statements in python:**
>
> If car_year is before 1967, print "Probably has few safety features."
> (without quotes).
>
> If after 1969, print "Probably has seat belts.".
>
> If after 1990, print "Probably has electronic stability control.".
>
> If after 2002, print "Probably has airbags.".
>
> End each phrase with period and newline. Remember that print()
> automatically adds a newline.
>
> Ex: car_year = 1995 prints:
>
> Probably has seat belts.
>
> Probably has electronic stability control.

My code:

```
car_year = int(input())

if car_year <= 1967:

    print('Probably has few safety features.')

if car_year >= 1970:

    print('Probably has seat belts.')

if car_year >= 1991:

    print('Probably has electronic stability control.')

if car_year >= 2002:

    print('Probably has airbags.')
```

I am unsure of what I am doing incorrectly.

1. When compared with the input 1967, my output is 'Probably has few safety features.' when the solution expected no output.
2. When compared with the input 2002, my output is 'Probably has self belts.', 'Probably has electronic stability control.', and 'Probably has airbags.' when the expected output is 'Probably has self belts.', 'Probably has electronic stability control.'.

Comment: Can you tell us what you expect to be the result of the expression `x <= 1967` for these values of `x`: 1966, 1967, 1968? (true or false). And which of these 3 years do you consider "before 1967"?

Answer (score 0):

The exercise tells you "before 1967" and "after 2002." Before and after mean that you should not include the year mentioned but rather consider all years prior/subsequent accordingly. You are using the inclusive >= and <= operators which will include 1967 and 2002 in your results when they should be excluded.

```
car_year = int(input())

if car_year < 1967:

    print('Probably has few safety features.')

if car_year > 1969:

    print('Probably has seat belts.')

if car_year > 1990:

    print('Probably has electronic stability control.')

if car_year > 2002:

    print('Probably has airbags.')
```